# Cant find method getPackages() in MainActivity.java for REACT-NATIVE

Tags: javascript, react-native, android-studio

Im building a music player and I need to get the metadata of the songs, for that im using this package:
`react-native-get-music-files`, following its instruction to install it says:

[image]

it says add to the list returned by the `getPackages()` method, but i think my android studio version is different and i dont have it, so dont know where to put it:

this is my MainActivity:

```
package com.musicplayer;

import com.reactlibrary.RNReatNativeGetMusicFilesPackage;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;

import expo.modules.splashscreen.singletons.SplashScreen;
import expo.modules.splashscreen.SplashScreenImageResizeMode;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // SplashScreen.show(...) has to be called after super.onCreate(...)
    // Below line is handled by '@expo/configure-splash-screen' command and it's discouraged to modify it manually
    SplashScreen.show(this, SplashScreenImageResizeMode.CONTAIN, ReactRootView.class, false);
  }


    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "main";
    }

    @Override
    protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
        return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
            @Override
            protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
                return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when installing [`react-native-add-shorcut`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-add-shortcut?activeTab=readme).

I found someone who had [the same issue](https://github.com/voximplant/react-native-demo/issues/4) and was told that this was changed in RN +29. Now, `getPackages()` is found in `android/app/main/java/[...]/MainApplication.java`.

Still, when I added it there I got an error saying the package was being added twice. It Seems like this is taken care of in `/android/app/build/generated/[...]/PackageList.java` after running `react-native run-android`. I simply didn't add it and now it's working for me.